# validate the date of an 'event' on ruby on rails using activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How do I validate a date so i can only `show/create` an event thats in the present or future, so not in the past? I am using activerecord and this code would either be located in the `show.html.erb` folder of the event or the controller

Comment: are you working with time_zones?  and also is it only `Date` or `DateTime`?

Comment: not that i know of . only date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating/updating use [date_validator gem](https://github.com/codegram/date_validator) like this

```
validates :date,
          date: { after: Proc.new { Date.today } } #, on: :create # if you want only to validate on creation
```

For show you can use before_action in controller like this

```
def EventController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event
  before_action :check_date

  ...

  private

  def check_date
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'This event has ended' if @event.date < Date.today
  end
end
```